# From where can I get english translation of BhaavaArthBodhini or Critical Edition Of RamCharitManas by Swami RamBhadrAcharya?

Tags: ramayana, rama, ramcharitmanas, ramanandi

I would like to know where I can get either soft or hard copy of english translation of Swami RamaBhadrAcharya's critical edition of Tulsi Das's Sri RamCharitManas aslo known as BhavaArthaBodhini.
I think the hindi version of the book is available online but I can't seem to find english translation.

Comment: I don't think the book was ever translated into English.

Answer (score -2):

You may get hindi version of Bhavarthabodhini (by Swami Rambhadracharya ji maharaj) from

https://archive.org/details/JR2008Bhavarthabodhini

IMHO, there is no english translation available. So you can not find its english translation

Comment: As I said in the question, the hindi version is available online. I am looking for the english translation.The link in your answer is for hindi version.

Comment: @RishX : where there is a crisis, there is an opportunity. As it has not been translated, so do translation of it to english and become immortal :-)